# Send command output back to previous subshell in pipe for processing

Tags: bash, sed, file-descriptor, xmllint

Given [this html5 page](https://www.w3.org/TR/XHTMLplusMathMLplusSVG/sample.xhtml), process it with `xmllint` interactively with previous subshell using a file descriptor.
To be applied on [xml2xpath OS project](https://github.com/mluis7/xml2xpath).

**How to reproduce**:  Run the script snippet on "The problem" section

**Base command is**:

```
(echo 'xpath //*'; echo "bye") | xmllint --shell html5.html
```

Which gives the source output to be processed:

```
/ > xpath //*
Object is a Node Set :
Set contains 346 nodes:
1  ELEMENT html
    default namespace href=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
    ATTRIBUTE lang
      TEXT
        content=en
    ATTRIBUTE dir
      TEXT
        content=ltr
2  ELEMENT head
3  ELEMENT title
...
202  ELEMENT div
    default namespace href=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
203  ELEMENT p
204  ELEMENT code
205  ELEMENT math
    default namespace href=http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML
...
345  ELEMENT mo
346  ELEMENT mn
/ > bye
```

**The goal** is to join lines containing `namespace` to previous line, show `n  ELEMENT name` as `n name`, ignore the rest (and send more commands to `xmllint`).
The following command gives **the correct lines** expected to appear on previous subshell

```
(echo 'xpath //*' )| xmllint --shell $proj/git/xml2xpath/tests/resources/html5.html | \
sed -nEe '{ :a; $!N;s/^([0-9]{1,5}) *ELEMENT *([^ ]*)\n +(default)? ?namespace ([a-z]+)? ?href=([^=]+)/\1 \2 \3\4=\5/;ta; s/^([0-9]{1,5}) *ELEMENT *([^ ]*)/\1 \2/; /^[1-9]/ P;D }'

1 html default=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
2 head
3 title
4 link
5 link
6 link
7 link
8 body
9 h1
10 h2
...
```

**The problem**
Sending lines back to subshell through file descriptor does not join lines correctly, `namespace` info appears on its own item inside `arrns` array (next code sample).
So reading from file descriptor and processing with `sed` to fill an array is not working as expected. Also, trying to avoid post-processing or parsing the file more than 1 time in this stage.

Best approach so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget --no-clobber "https://www.w3.org/TR/XHTMLplusMathMLplusSVG/sample.xhtml" -O html5.html

fname='xff'
[ ! -p "$fname" ] && mkfifo "$fname"
exec 3<>"$fname"

cat /dev/null > tmp.log

stop='dir xxxxxxx'

function parse_line(){
    while read -r -u 3 xline; do 
        printf "%s\n" "$xline"
        if [ "$xline" == "/ > $stop" ]; then 
            break 
        fi
    done | sed -nEe '{ :a; $!N;s/^([0-9]{1,5}) *ELEMENT *([^ ]*)\n +(default)? ?namespace ([a-z]+)? ?href=([^=]+)/\1 \2 \3\4=\5/;ta; s/^([0-9]{1,5}) *ELEMENT *([^ ]*)/\1 \2/; /^[1-9]|namespace/ P;D }'
}

(
    echo 'xpath //*'
    echo "$stop"
    IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a arrns < <(parse_line && printf '\0')
    
    # print to file temporarily for debugging and avoid sending to xmllint shell 
    printf "%s\n" "${arrns[@]}" >> tmp.log
    echo "OUT OF LOOP 1 ${#arrns[@]}" >> tmp.log
    echo "bye"
) | xmllint --shell html5.html >&3

exec 3>&-
rm xff
cat tmp.log
```

Parsing all lines from fd 3 to a variable and then applying `sed` gave the same result.

**Showing contents of `arrns`** on `tmp.log` (almost correct):

```
1 html
default namespace href=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
2 head
3 title
4 link
5 link
...
239 math
default namespace href=http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML
...
OUT OF LOOP 1 354
```

Lines 1 and 239 on the sample should look

```
239 math default=http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML
```

Which could allow with a bit of processing to forward this command to `xmllint` from the same subshell to set namespaces as they appear in the document.

```
setns default=http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML
```

Comment: What is your question, exactly? An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would definitely help.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Thanks, I appreciate your comment. Lines containing `namespace` are not joined to previous line. On the other hand, the question explains the problem and offers the code to reproduce. Might not be minimum to some people but it's complete and reproducible for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason this `while read` loop does not emulate the `xmllint` output and made the original `sed` command to fail

```
while read -r -u 3 xline; do ... ; done
```

Fixed the `sed` command after the loop and now the output is correct

```
sed -E -e :a -e '/^[1-9]/,/^(default|namespace)/ { $!N;s/\n(default|namespace)/ \1/;ta }' \
-e 's/^([0-9]{1,5}) *ELEMENT *([^ ]*)/\1 \2/' \
-e 's/(default)? ?namespace( [a-z0-9]+)? ?href=([^=]+)/\1\2=\3/g' \
-e '/^[1-9]/ P;D'
```

Order matters here it seems

**1- Join lines as expected**
`sed -E -e :a -e '/^[1-9]/,/^(default|namespace)/ { $!N;s/\n(default|namespace)/ \1/;ta }'`

```
1  ELEMENT html
default namespace href=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
```

Becomes

```
1  ELEMENT html default namespace href=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
```

**2- Handle `*ELEMENT*` lines**
`-e 's/^([0-9]{1,5}) *ELEMENT *([^ ]*)/\1 \2/'`

Before: `1  ELEMENT html`
After : `1 html`

**3- Handle `*namespace*` part of step 1 result**
`-e 's/(default)? ?namespace( [a-z0-9]+)? ?href=([^=]+)/\1\2=\3/g'`

Before: `1 html default namespace href=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`
After : `1 html default=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`

**4- Print lines starting with a number**
`-e '/^[1-9]/ P;D'`

**Wrong result**:

```
1 html
default namespace href=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
2 head
...
191 svg:svg
namespace svg href=http://www.w3.org/2000/svg
...
```

**Correct result** after fix:

```
1 html default=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
2 head
...
191 svg:svg svg=http://www.w3.org/2000/svg
...
```